# angular.js ng-repeat - check if conditional is true then use another collection

Tags: javascript, angularjs, if-statement, angularjs-ng-repeat

I'm wondering is it possible to check what collection to use inside `ng-repeat`?

For example, in my controller I have 2 arrays of data fetched from server, now I use `ng-switch` to switch between them, check this jsbin - http://jsbin.com/diyefevi/1/edit?html,js,output

The problem is that these `li` views in my real application are big but very similar.. so I really would like to **use 1 `ng-repeat` instead of 2**.

So I wonder if something like `ng-repeat="book in if list==='adultBooks' adultBooks else childBooks"` is possible in Angular?

Thanks!

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Try this ...

In your **controller**

```
$scope.getDataSource=function(condition){

  if(condition){ return dataSource1; }
  return dataSource2;
};
```

In your **Html**

```
ng-repeat="book in getDataSource(/*condition*/)
```

MVVM Pattern advises to put our logic always in the controller and not in the view(HTML). If you ever find yourself adding "logic" in your view probably there is an alternate "better" way to do it.

But just for "*fun*" you can do this too:

```
ng-repeat="book in {true: adultBooks, false: childBooks}[list==='adultBooks']"
```

Like this:

```
<li ng-repeat="book in {true: childBooks, false:adultBooks}[list==='childBooks']">{{book.name}
```

Here is the full sample:

http://jsbin.com/diyefevi/5/edit?html,js,output

Comment: Depends, doesn't it?  I mean if the view will always consistently apply the same logic...

Comment: @DaveKaye not on this question, it may depend if this solution is applied on other scenarios but not on this one.

Answer (score 2):

The simplest solutions I can think of would be to define a new array on the scope which you set the other arrays to when you need.

E.g. http://jsbin.com/diyefevi/4/edit?html,js,output

Answer (score 2):

Something like this would eliminate the need for ng-switch:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="test">
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.14/angular.min.js"></script>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
  <a href="" ng-click="toggleList()">Toggle List</a>
  <h1>{{list}}</h1>
  <ul>
      <li ng-repeat="book in getBooks()">{{book.name}}</li>
  </ul>
</body>
</html>
```

and the js:

```
var app = angular.module('test', []);
app.controller('MainCtrl', function ($scope) {
  $scope.list = 'childBooks';

  $scope.childBooks = [{name: 'Dodobird'}, {name: 'Catty Red Hat'}];

  $scope.adultBooks = [{name: 'Little Lady'}, {name: 'Johny Doe'}];

  $scope.toggleList = function () {
    $scope.list = $scope.list === 'childBooks' ? 'adultBooks' : 'childBooks';
  };

  $scope.getBooks = function() {
    if($scope.list == 'adultBooks') {
      return $scope.adultBooks;
    } else {
      return $scope.childBooks;
    }
  }
});
```

Here is the [jsbin code](http://jsbin.com/gajif/1/edit)