# angularjs ng-repeat increment in if-condition

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I Want to set a Variable outside ng-repeat and increment it inside of ng-if.
Only when the condition is false, the variable should incremented.

In Twig it looks like:

```
{% for plan in entity.plan %}  
   {% set spieltag = 0 %} <!-- sets the variable inside loop -->

   {% if (plan.spieltag != spieltag)  %}
   <tr class="bg-info">
      <td colspan="7">Spieltag: {{ plan.spieltag }}</td>
      <td></td>
   </tr>

{% set spieltag = spieltag +1 %} <!-- only increments when condition is false -->
{% endif %}
<tr>
    <!-- some stuff that always shown  
</tr>
{% endfor %}
```

In Angular i have a tr-loop:

```
<tr data-ng-repeat="row in liga.plan" data-ng-init="spieltag = 0">
   <!-- shows all the stuff -->
</tr>
```

I know the ng-init is on the wrong place, but where should i take it and how can i increment it only when the condition is false?

Data from the loop:

```
[{
    plan: [
        {spieltag: 1, home: foo, guest: bar},
        {spieltag: 1, home: foo1, guest: bar1},
        {spieltag: 1, home: foo2, guest: bar2},
        {spieltag: 2, home: bar, guest: foo},
        {spieltag: 2, home: bar1, guest: foo1},
        {spieltag: 2, home: bar2, guest: foo2},
    ]

}]
```

Comment: This is not the right approach. Angular way of doing things is to separate view from business logic. The view should be stupid a d view the data not modify. The controller is the place to prepare the data. From phone I can't create an example for you hence a comment not an answer.

Comment: angular may run expressions hundred of times, while you think once. putting counter in template is wrong way in angular.

Answer (score 0):

Technically, I think you're asking the same thing as this guy:
[angular.js ng-repeat - check if conditional is true then use another collection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23088523/angular-js-ng-repeat-check-if-conditional-is-true-then-use-another-collection)

So, you'd have to define a function in your ng-controller that checks for the variable. Would that work for you?