# Angular js - how to write code for ng-repeat based on condition

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am developing the project for hotel POS system. I am taking the orders from the customer. There are 2 types of orders present in the system as:

1. Take Away Orders.
2. Home delivery Orders.

In the **orders** table I am storing all the orders.
I am fetching the takeaway orders in **allCurrentTakeAwayOrder**
and home delivery orders in **allcurrentHMOrder**
I want to show the takeaway orders and Home delivery orders in different sections.

I want to put condition if heading is **Take Away** then ng-repeat should take values from **allCurrentTakeAwayOrder** if its **Home Delivery** then from **allcurrentHMOrder** as:

```
<tr ng-repeat='orders in allCurrentTakeAwayOrder if heading=Take Away or
   orders in allcurrentHMOrder if heading=Home Delivery' >
</tr>
```

Comment: Or you can just create your own filter, compare the value as you do here and return true or false to let ng-repeat know if he should show the tested element or not. Here is a documentation link: https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/filter (scroll down until you find the part about custom filters).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really want to use a condition inside your ng-repeat, I would suggest using a ternary operator, like this:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="condition" ng-model="condition" />
<ul ng-init="numbers=[1,2,3];letters=['a','b','c'];">
  <li ng-repeat="i in (condition ? numbers : letters)">
    {{i}}
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: IMHO that's a bit complicated and you should not do that in your HTML for performance purposes. Not the best answer yet, i recommend you to avoid that.

Answer (score 1):

Most natural way to make it work is to construct a single collection of both `allCurrentTakeAwayOrder` and `allcurrentHMOrder` as `orders` and make sure it's items contains property type (TakeAway/Delivery). In that case, you will be able to change your code like this:

```
ng-repeat="order in orders | filter:{type:heading}"
```

Answer (score 1):

i have use ng-if inside ng-repeat

```
<tr ng-repeat='orders in allCurrentTakeAwayOrder | filter:{type:heading}' >
    <label ng-if="orders.heading == 'Take Away' || orders.heading == 'Home Delivery'">

    </label>
 </tr>
```

i think it may help you.

Comment: That might be `orders.heading` and not simply `orders` that he should compare in your ng-if, except that, this should work.

Comment: exactly, it should be orders.heading

Answer (score 0):

Define a `$scope` variable as `data` : `$scope.data`

then in HTML :

```
<tr ng-repeat='orders in data' >
    ...
</tr>
```

JS - Controller :

```
$scope.data = [];
if($scope.heading == 'Take Away') {
    $scope.data = angular.copy(allCurrentTakeAwayOrder);
} else if($scope.heading == 'Home Delivery') {
    $scope.data = angular.copy(allcurrentHMOrder);
} else {
    // Any default code or change any one condition to incorporate in this block and remove else if
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You may need to use comparator for this.

```
$scope.values = ["Take Away", "Home Delivery"]; 

$scope.comparator = function(expected, actual){  
  return actual.indexOf(expected) > -1;
}

<tr ng-repeat='orders in allCurrentTakeAwayOrder | filter:{heading:values}:comparator' >

</tr>
```

Comment: Why do you need custom filter for that? :)

Comment: Typo. Not a custom filter, we can use comparator

Answer (score 0):

Please follow this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23088523/angular-js-ng-repeat-check-if-conditional-is-true-then-use-another-collection) for a good resolution to the problem.

However the summary for your case is as follows:

```
<tr ng-repeat="orders in {true: allCurrentTakeAwayOrder, false:allcurrentHMOrder}[heading==='Take Away']">

  //Output something

</tr>
```

Hope this helps.