# Exclude elements in a nested array from ng-repeat without ng-if

Tags: javascript, angularjs, multidimensional-array, angularjs-ng-repeat

Given a nested array, how can I filter these values in an ng-repeat without having to use ng-if.

The reason not to use an ng-if, is that I need zero values to not take up an $index, because I need to match that index with something else that is happening in this view. So for example this doesn't work for me atm:

```
<tr ng-if="row.value[0] !== 0 || row.value[1] !== 0" ng-repeat="row in chart.values track by $index">
```

In the image below, for example if value[0] or value[1] were zero under Asian/Indian, then they shouldn't appear in the ng-repeat. The data looks as follows:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quick suggestion: Perform your business logic back where ever you are generating the array, not in your ng-repeat

Something like here, but instead of changing the data source, make your comparison: [angular.js ng-repeat - check if conditional is true then use another collection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23088523/angular-js-ng-repeat-check-if-conditional-is-true-then-use-another-collection)

Comment: Thanks, but you could please provide an example! Pretty pls.

Comment: Hey, I ended up doing this... thanks for the tip. Better to use the data you need from where the data comes from rather than complicate your life in the view.

Comment: Glad this worked out for you. Check out some MVC principles. It's a good rule of thumb to not have any computation happening in your view. There are always exceptions to any rule though.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `ng-show` and evaluate in a method; that would preserve the  `$index`'es :

```js
$scope.showRow = function(row) {
  return row.value[0] !== 0 || row.value[1]!== 0
}
```

```html
<tr ng-repeat="row in chart.values track by $index" ng-show="showRow(row)">
```

---

**Update**. If you not want to preserve the `$index`'es you could modify the above `showRow` to :

```js
$scope.showRow = function(row) {
  return !(row.value[0] == 0 || row.value[1] == 0)
}
```

and then use it as a `filter` instead :

```html
<tr ng-repeat="row in chart.values | filter:showRow track by $index">
```

By that the tracked `$index`'es will be 0,1,2,3,4...etc regardless of whatever there is filtered out.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, but whatever isn't shown is still taking up an index, I don't want it to ever to be evaluated in the ng-repeat.

Comment: hey @EdgarQuintero, I thought you wanted to preserve the `$index`? Guess I misunderstood, but you can skip unwanted elements completely by using a `filter` instead. Have updated the answer. Here is a demo -> **http://plnkr.co/edit/HIMkYDD859fiyZ6a7iiv?p=preview**